# I'm getting following error when I'm trying for log4j.

Tags: java, log4j, classloader, log4j2

I got following error while I'm working with log4j. Can any one guess what may be the issue ? 
Thanks in advance

```
log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.

log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by 

log4j:ERROR [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@43540a77] whereas object of type 

log4j:ERROR "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" was loaded by [WebAppClassLoader].

log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "stdout".
```

These are the lines written in log4j.properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=error, stdout

log4j.logger.java.sql=error
log4j.logger.com.example.test=error

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{DATE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: looks like two log4j jars are present, one in tomcat/lib and other in webapp

Comment: @sidgate : I just have checked but not found any lib in tomcat/lib. lib log4j-1.2.16.jar is present in webapps only. It looks like some other issue ?

Comment: Check again. Maybe someone put log4j into jre/lib/ext? But the fact that it even shows the two classloaders involved is a very strong argument pro multiple locations